# xcode: action segue only has Push, Modal and Custom

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue

Why my action segue of storyboard only Push, Modal and Custom(Picture1).
Picture1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWnqi.png

I want the action segue to display show, show detail...

How to display the show, show detail on the action segue?

Thank you

---

Why I have no the action 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r3f9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select segue, on the right pane select 'Attributes Inspector' and see 'Kind' field. You can select desired segue type:

[image]

[image]

If you don't see 'Adaptive Segues' section this means storyboard is not using 'Size Classes', to enable it, select storyboard then 'File Inspector', under 'Interface Builder Document' section check 'Use Size Classes' option.

[image]

Comment: Where is the 'Attributes Inspector', Can you cut yo picture for me? Thank you

Comment: I can not see your action

Comment: You have to enable 'Use Size Classes' option

Comment: how to enable 'Use Suze Classes'?

Comment: In my case "Use Trait variations" under File Inspector was unchecked. Checking it showed all the options.

Answer (score 1):

Just `select segue -> in right panel select attribute inspector -> kind` , there you can see all the options...

[image]  [image]

Comment: I can not see your action

Comment: Sorry, you can help me to fix this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955521/swift-click-button-to-secondviewcontroller-if-input-is-correct